# Why would I write a Collectives article instead of a blog post?

Tags: discussion, collectives, articles

The R collective was opened earlier this year, and I am trying to understand the role of articles within the collective.

Unless one is a Recognized Member of the collective, a person who wants to write an article must: propose it, have the proposal reviewed, write a draft, and respond to feedback before the article would be published.

Within the R community, it's a lot easier to register as a blog with *r-bloggers.com* and start writing articles that are immediately published to the readers of R-Bloggers.

Why would someone jump through the hoops to write a Stack Overflow Collectives article when lower friction alternatives to distributing one's content exist?

On the contrary, it seems easier to expand a Stack Overflow answer into a blog post that can be published elsewhere, like I did with [Estimating the Runtime of an R Script](https://lgreski.github.io/dsdepot/2020/07/01/estimating-R-script-runtime.html) which was based on my answer to [How to estimate R script running time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447471/how-to-estimate-r-script-running-time).

Comment: Maybe you _want_ feedback.  Writing a good technical article is _hard_, and feedback helps a lot.

Comment: Because the R collective on SO is the premier location for all things R, obviously

Comment: It’s a quite ridiculous idea. Maybe I do want to write an article on SO. Well, I can’t, because there doesn’t exist any collective for the fields I’d write articles for.

Comment: @RyanM - fair point *writing a good technical article is hard*, but the way collectives articles are described, the process seems more like a gatekeeping function than "support for article writers."

Comment: Because SO is intended to be a repository of *good* content.